# EZ PUBLISH Backend Location

Tags: php, content-management-system, ezpublish

where can I find this page in ez publish root directory?

[image]

I'm new to this so please bear with me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `admin/templates/user/login.tpl`

Comment: Hi sir does it reside inside design folder?

`design/admin/templates/user/login.tpl`

Comment: yes its in ezlegacy admin design (depending on the version of ezpublish you're using)

Comment: coz I'm planning to put a metadata there... but I can't find the `<head>` tag there...do you have any idea where can I find the whole file?

Comment: I already got it sir.. the whole file is in `design/admin/templates/loginpagelayout.tpl`.. thanks for the help...